# Can't convert frozen Inception graph .pb created with Docker to .tflite

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, command-line, tensorflow-lite

I have created a my `saved_model.pb` through Docker in my macOS device.

After trying `tflite_convert --output_file=./myModels/mymodel.tflite --saved_model_dir=./myModels/` it is outputing the following error requiring me a tag argument:

> "ValueError: Importing a SavedModel with tf.saved_model.load requires a 'tags=' argument if there is more than one MetaGraph. Got 'tags=None', but there are 0 MetaGraphs in the SavedModel with tag sets []. Pass a 'tags=' argument to load this SavedModel."

I have also tried another command where you will have to provide the input and output arrays but I do know know which ones are my arrays to put in those fields. Anybody got this problem and solved it before? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the tags in your saved model using the saved_model_cli:

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#saved_model_cli

`$ saved_model_cli show --dir ./myModels/ --all`

Pass the required tags with
`--saved_model_tag_set` to tflite_convert.